# Invite friends to like FB page with new timeline?

Tags: facebook

How can I do the same as with our old Facebook Pages, Personally send our friend invitations to like our page? I can't find this feature within the new timeline layout?

Is this still possible - I'm not ready to launch an ad or want to post on my wall just yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on top of What Alexander said, BUT;

You have to switch to your 'Real / Personal account' > Go back to said page > THEN send invites to friends. This was my struggle.

Comment: Hey, is this available for non admins also? This was there in the facebook page before the timeline but in the timeline its not there.

Answer (score 4):

When you go to the page with an administrator account at top there is a button **"Buld Audience"**. Click it and you will see different options.

Comment: Thank you, but I think - Ultimately my struggle was you cannot be logged into your Page your trying to get liked. You have to switch to your 'Real / Personal account' > Go back to said page > THEN send invites. Kinda lame, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the admin panel - http://cl.ly/image/0G3v1j0E3d23 (screenshot)

Also friends (non-admins) can not invite their friends.  They can only share the page on their wall - https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=201564956553667